# RoboCup Junior IR Ball detection

Tags: infrared, demodulation

RoboCup Junior uses an IR ball which emits [pulsing infrared light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKtPq.png) (before this it was a steady beam which sensors could not differentiate from environmental sources). A [presentation](http://rcj.robocup.org/rcj2009/newball/cheapRCJ05sensors-RobotDemos09.pdf)  outlining the possible methods of detecting the ball mentioned the use of TSOP1138s and microcontroller programming.

What would be the best way to use an Arduino/ATmega to read the pulses? The timings involved are very small, and with an interrupt I am unable to use timing functions.

EDIT: After a little mucking around it seems like I should have used the TSOP1140 instead. If anyone can explain how these little guys work it would be great help, but in the meantime I shall wait for my order to arrive.

Comment: Please bring all relevant info here so that the question can remain independent of other sources. Links to the actual sites should only be used to supplement the question.

Comment: No, I'm not going to chase down links to get basic information about your question.  As it stands, this is a poorly asked question and should be closed.  You need to fix it before 4 additional close votes.  The clock is ticking.

Comment: Three left now... Act now before stocks run out!!!

Comment: While I agree that the question could use improvement, please cease this **childish** race between closing and editing; it is after all a weekend, and it's entirely plausible the poster won't be back until Monday.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, while it may seem childish, it really is simple. The moment the question has been corrected/improved to minimum quality standards the question has a race to reopen. If the question is closed all the asked must do is correct the issues and either flag for a moderator to review or allow the community to naturally reopen it in a race. Close is not permanent and asking users not to edit to improve questions is counterproductive, why not improve questions?

Comment: @Kortuk - that's a deeply flawed theory, which ignores the psychological effect of "rejecting" someone (you see it as their question, they see it as personal) and the practicality that it's harder to undo something than it is to refrain from doing it in the first place.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, or you can show them that we attempt to keep a high quality site, even if things were not implemented in the past. I am a strong believer that leaving a kind comment explaining what is happening and the fact that nothing is permanent. I have seen many many times in the past on chiphacker and as the site was first open that with a kind comment asking for help but no close users would just wait and see whom would sympathy answer.If you close it until correction they must get a good question that matches what answers are coming.

Comment: @Kortuk - Your attitude is counterproductive and results in a small user community which projects an impression of exclusivity.  There is nothing wrong with extra-work-required questions just sitting. Perhaps they'll provide an opportunity for a newly registered user to gain some reputation by answering.  If people really dislike the form of a question, downvoting it could be a good idea; that merely expresses personal displeasure, *without banning others from providing an answer*

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have seen a few times that you state with high confidence that the site is actually worse off by closing questions, but you have not provided any factual evidence of this. What our basis is off of is evidence that the SE founders have seen from the progression of sites. I am in no position to say if their "research" is factually sound or not, but I do know I have to trust it much more then someone who has no data to back their statements up with.

Comment: For example, your statement of "projects an impression of exclusivity", we do actually want to have some degree of exclusivity in order to keep quality high. It has been found in the past (even back to the user group days) that when a community gets filled with very poor questions, experts get tired of it and eventually just leaving causing the whole community to go down hill. This is not to say that we shouldn't be more open to helping people shape their questions to be better questions, but we also don't want all of the experts to leave as well.

Comment: @Kellenjb "we do actually want to have some degree of exclusivity" You may see this as quality of questions, but the way it comes out is being exclusive with regard to people.  If "experts" are annoyed by questions from newer users, they should be reading through filters as is usual on a larger stack exchange site.  The whole close and re-open idea is deeply flawed - it smacks of personal rejection, rarely works, forces those with an answer to post it as a comment and **wastes everyones time** compared to just ignoring or downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach is to make an interrupt handler that will be invoked each time the IR receiver receives a pulse.

When you receive each pulse, you capture the elapsed time from the previous pulse.  If the elapsed time is 25 microseconds, you know you are in the middle of receiving a burst of pulses, and you should be counting them.  If there's a gap of 346 microseconds or more, you know you are in the inter-transmit gap.  You can then count the pulses you have received.  If there are 8 pulses, you know the ball is far away, since you only received the highest strength pulses.  If there are 12 pulses, it's a little bit closer. Likewise until you receive 20 pulses, meaning you are the closest to the ball you can measure.

Of course, being in the real world you might miss a pulse or two for some reason, so your counting method should take that into account.  Likewise, the timing might be a little bit off (either your clock or the ball's clock might be slightly off), so that would need to be taken into account as well.  If the ball is not visible at all, there won't be any pulses read.

In the Arduino environment, we would use the [interrupt functions](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt) and the basic code would look something like this.  Assume the input is on digital pin 7.

```
volatile int npulses = 0;             // number of pulses received in this "set"
volatile unsigned long lasttime = 0;  // timestamp of last pulse received
volatile int distance = 0;


void dopulse()
{
    unsigned long now;  // the current time in microseconds
    now = micros();
    elapsed = now - lasttime;
    lasttime = now;
    if (elapsed > 300) {
        distance = npulses;
        npulses = 1;
   }
   else {
       npulses += 1;
   }
}

void setup()
{
    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
    attachInterrupt(7, dopulse, RISING);
    ...
}
```

Comment: They advise RC filtering them so that each burst appears as a single pulse.

Comment: +1 -1 +1 -  for understanding the problem and commenting on it's solution without apparently being aware that the basic principal of operation is not understood by some :-)

Answer (score 0):

( I am terribly sorry about the poor quality of my question, but I also thank the forgiveness of the community. I will polish it up. )

The TSOP1140s have arrived, and they work wonderfully. All that was needed to read the IR was a simple pulseIn() with appropriate timeouts (about 2000µS was sufficient) because the signal had already been demodulated by the sensor.

Here is the portion of code that I used with the sensor hooked up to pin 2.

```
void loop()
{
  duration = pulseIn(2,LOW,2000);
  if(duration)
  {
    total -= samples[index]; samples[index] = duration;
    total += samples[index]; index = (index+1)%SAMPLES;
    average = total/SAMPLES;
    Serial.println(average);
  }
  // clear cache if nothing detected
  else { for(byte i=0;i<SAMPLES;i++){ samples[i]=0; } total=0; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an RC filter on the output. The RC filter converts your pulse to analog voltage easily then ADC converter can be used.
The value can be something like this:
R = 22k ohm
C = 1uF

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Note that the original question is from eight years ago and the OP never came back to the site! There is a CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar if you ever want to add a schematic.